# C++ No appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am getting the error "A: No appropriate default constructor available." The line number it points me to is the line where I initialize class B .

I have tried doing an initialization list, as was suggested in similar posts, but it did not resolve the error.

The program has lots of other functions which I cut out for the purpose of readability and simplicity, as they are not related to the error.

I am creating a B object, which in the constructor creates two class A objects, each of which receives a pointer to a separate function.

```
// Class A
template <typename T> class A   
{
public:

// constructor
A(int c, bool(*Ptr)(T, T));
};


// Class B
template <typename T> class B
{
public:
//constructor
B(int c);

A <T> oneHolder;   // Class A objects
A <T> twoHolder;

bool(*lowPtr)(T, T) = &lowerThan;           // pointer to a function
bool(*highPtr)(T, T) = &higherThan;         // pointer to a function
};

//Class A constructor
template <typename T>
A<T>::A(int c, bool(*fPtr)(T, T)) {

    m_Size = c;
    // set function pointer
    func_ptr = fPtr;

}


//B Constructor
template <typename T>
B<T>::B(int c){ // Might need initialization list, error points here

    m_Size = c;

    // Create two A objects
    A<T> one(c, lowPtr); // passing function pointer
    A<T> two(c, highPtr);


    lowHolder = one;
    highHolder = two;

}
```

Comment: There is no default constructor for `one` and `two`, so you must initialize them

Comment: Please post a MCVE , your code uses several undeclared identifiers (e.g. `lowerThan`, `lowHolder`)

Comment: A ctor-initializer-list is the right way to solve this, what went wrong when you tried?

Answer (score 3):

You should call constructor of A from constructor of B. Class A doesn't have default constructor.

If you will change A's constructor to the following it will work

```
A(int c = 0, bool(*Ptr)(T, T) = nullptr);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on when you say A does not have a default constructor? In B when I create two A objects, shouldn't that call A's constructor function?

Comment: @Grehgous, you need to provide arguments for constructors of B's member variables `oneHolder` and `twoHolder`.

Comment: @Grehgous e.g. like this `template <typename T> B<T>::B(int c) : oneHolder(...), twoHolder(...) { ... }`